# Draw graph of function with certain trait

Tags: functions

if you had an assignment to draw arbitrary function which is even/odd and is not continuous in point x=1, how would you do that?

I am not quite sure if function is even if it is not continuous in one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is even when $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$. Then your function won't be continuous for $x=-1$ either.

A simple example is
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{if }x\neq\pm1;\\0&\text{if }x=\pm1.\end{cases}$$

Similarly, if we want an odd function $(f(x)=-f(-x))$ not continuous at $x=-1$, it won't be continuous at $x=1$.

A simple example is
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^3&\text{if }x\neq\pm1;\\0&\text{if }x=\pm1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Whole new view for me :-). At first I thought it was not possible to construct that function, because if it is not continuous only in x=1, it can not be even function. But if the function is also discontinous in x=-1, then it is possible.

Comment: Have one more question: If that function is not continuous in points +-1, then it does not have derivation in those points, am I right? :)

Comment: @naruto25 Yes this function couldn't be derive in $\pm1$.

Comment: I have one similar question, so I write it here. Arbitraty odd function which is defined on all real numbers and does not have derivation in x=-1. It can be f(x) = x^3 for all x except +-1 and 0(zero) for x=+-1?

Comment: @naruto25 you are right for your odd function. You could edit your question to include this one too, I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: Sorry for interupting, but it would be the same for y=x function(speaking about that odd)? Know it is going to be true, but want to be sure :).

Comment: @naruto25 Yes $y = x$ is an odd function. An example could be created with this function.